# Vim: Aligning insertion point with left side of column

Tags: key-bindings, indentation

Suppose I have this (where my insertion point is designated "|"):

```
col1           col2

thing          oeueaoue|
another
something
test
```

What keystroke(s) would I use so the insertion point jumps to here:

```
col1           col2

thing          oeueaoue
another        |
something
test
```

?

Is <kbd>return</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>… (normal mode) the only way?

Comment: How do you feel about using `'virtualedit'`? You could use `set virtualedit=all`. Then you can just move to where you want to start editing.

Comment: @PeterRincker That wouldn't be a very automated way of doing it, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431508/1429450):

> When there are many lines to edit, it can be useful to map the return
>   key temporarily, something like that in your case:
>
> ```
> inoremap <buffer> <cr> <esc>jA<tab>
> ```
>
> When you're done, just cancel the map:
>
> ```
> iunmap <buffer> <cr>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:Tabularize`](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) to do this.

```
:Tabularize /\s\+\zs/l1
```

There are plenty of other alignment plugins. e.g. [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) and [lion.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion). I would recommend installing an alignment tool if this becomes common.

If you want it automated then you can do something similar to Tim Pope's [cucumbertables.vim](https://gist.github.com/tpope/287147). Example:

```
inoremap <silent> <space>   <space>.<Esc>:call <SID>align()<CR>"_s

function! s:align()
  let p = '^\%(\w\+\s\+\)\+\w\+$'
  if exists(':Tabularize') && getline('.') =~# '^\w\+\s' && (getline(line('.')-1) =~# p || getline(line('.')+1) =~# p)
    let column = strlen(substitute(substitute(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'\S\+','.','g'), '\s*', '', 'g'))
    Tabularize/\s\+\zs/l1
    normal! 0
    call search(repeat('\w\+\s\+',column-1) . '.', 'ce', line('.'))
  endif
endfunction
```

Note: I have not fully tested this code. Use as is.

I would recommend this to be a buffer local mapping. See `:h map-local`.

Want a more native/simpler approach? Use `<c-y>` to copy a character right above the current location. You can simply spam `<c-y>` until you have your whitespace alignment. See `:h i_CTRL-y` for more information.